# MATLAB name clash: "wrong number of arguments"

Tags: function, matlab

It seems I have a MATLAB name clash with one of my variables called "annotation" and the built-in MATLAB function "annotation".

In my function, I am loading a .mat file containing the variable annotation and then try to use it as an argument to another function. A minimal working example looks like this:

```
function test()

    filenames = { 'file1.mat', 'file2.mat', 'file3.mat' };

    for i = 1:numel(filenames)
        in_file = char(filenames{i});
        out_file = strrep(in_file, '.mat', '_out.mat');

        prepare(out_file); % do something with the out file

        load(out_file);  % contains one variable named "annotation"
        which annotation % just to be sure

        other_function(annotation);
    end
end

function prepare(filename)
    annotation = rand(25, 1);
    save(filename);
end

function other_function(annotation)
    whos % just a stub - see whether it has been called
end
```

Now, in my function prepare I made sure the file contains a variable named "annotation". When I load it in the main function's loop, the "which" command tells me it exists as a variable, but in the call of other_function, MATLAB tries to call the function "annotation":

> annotation is a variable.
>
> ??? Error using ==> annotation at 71
>
> Not enough input arguments
>
> Error in ==> test at 14
>
> ```
>         other_function(annotation);
> ```

I am confused because I am using the variable name "annotation" in several parts of my program, also as parameter in function calls. The only explanation I can imagine is that MATLAB somehow precompiles my code - at "compile time", the variable "annotation" is not visible. However, at runtime it is found as can be seen from the output of the "which" command.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Many thanks in advance.

Note: I am using MATLAB 7.12.0 (R2011a).

Comment: even you have success in other cases, all I would do is changing the name of your variable annotation.Well, I can't see annotation as variable in your code as declared. As I understand Matlab, it just overwrites everything without asking because it is script language. Can you go throuhg with debugger and see what's inside annotation at "which"?

Comment: the debugger will say that annotation is a variable, and if you type `annotation` into the debugger, it will evaluate it without an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit strange! I found the same thing. Basically, workspace variables shouldn't be in scope from inside functions (though they are from inside scripts).

If you do `load(out_file)` this is loading the contents of that file into the workspace. So they shouldn't be in scope, I believe. Therefore, I'm surprised that `which(annotation)` calls it a variable, but not surprised that `annotation` is out of scope. (Actually, it looks like Matlab does sort-of put the variables in scope.)

I think that your idea about some kind of pre-processing on `annotation` sounds plausible. For example, if you replace `other_function(annotation)` with `eval('other_function(annotation);')`, then it will probably work (though I'm not saying that you *should* use `eval`, ever).

The best way to solve this would be to do something like:

```
data = load(out_file);
annotation = data.annotation;
```

so, load `out_file` into a struct, and then access the variable from there.

Comment: Thank you, that is definitely a nice idea. It will also make my code more understandable, because the variable annotation is explicitly declared.

Answer (score 2):

That is a beautifully obscure problem!  It is crappy design on Mathwork's part.  I would even call it a bug, interesting to see if they agree.

The short answer: you can "fix" this by adding the line `annnotation = 2;` anywhere in your code above your `load(out_file);` line.  Or `annotation = "roger";` or `annotation = false;`, it doesn't matter what type of variable you make annotation, as long as you explicitly force it to be a variable in your code.

Your code as written does not explicitly reference the variable `annotation`.  `annotation` just happens to be the name of a variable in the matlab file you load in to the function's workspace.  Somehow, this doesn't throw a runtime error, it just works wrong, which I would call a bug, but matlab might say is a documented limitation.  See their documentation at http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-39683.html#f4-75258 and tell me what you think.  That documentation seems to apply to nested functions, which your main function certainly is not.  CLEARLY your line `other_function(annotation)` should see `annotation` in the same scope as `which annotation` placed immediately above it sees.  (I just did that test and it says `annotation is a variable`).

Here is a minimal program that shows the problem:

```
function test()
  prepare('test.mat'); % writes i
  load('test.mat');  % contains one variable named "annotation"

  which annotation
  other_function(annotation);
end

function prepare(filename)
  annotation = 42; % the answer is 42
  save(filename);
end

function other_function(poodle)
  disp(poodle);
end
```

I invite you to submit this as a bug report at http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports using the "report bug" link on that page!  If you don't want to, I'll report it, just let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions on how to deal with that problem!
I agree with you that the documentation talks only about nested and "in some cases" anonymous functions. Furthermore, in the minimal example the function prepare is a subfunction, but in my original code where I found that problem, it is even a primary function.
I tried to submit a bug report on this, but unfortunately the

Comment: I tried to submit a bug report on this, but unfortunately the Mathworks site won't let me (had this problem before, something with my browser and cookies...). It would be nice if you could do so, and send me the link where I can follow this bug.

Comment: I have submitted [bug report](http://www.mathworks.com/support/service_requests/Service_Request_Detail.do?ID=632255&filter=&sort=&statusorder=0&dateorder=0).  Title of my but is **Function call accesses function instead of local variable.**

Answer (score 0):

This is (now?) documented behavior:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/troubleshooting-loading-variables-within-a-function.html